# inSSIDer are fetching different MAC address

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I am using the inSSIDer software provide by the Metageek to grab some details of wireless access point.We are using this to test whether there is interference around our area.
Everything works well,and I'm able to figure out some of the interference (channel overlapping).

But then when I'm doing the documentation I've realized that the MAC Address that has been captured by inSSIDer is different from the MAC address provided by the vendor.I'm pretty sure that the Access Point details is similar with the one available in the area.For your information, we are using HP Procurve Radio Port 220.

So anyone have any thought why this could happened?Or is there any "bug" with the software?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely familiar with HP Procruve APs, and not entirely clear on which MAC address you are referring to as provided by the vendor.  However, most enterprise vendors use the wired interface's MAC address for management and sometimes identification purposes.  This is because that is the MAC address you will see on the wired network.

For most enterprise APs, each AP/SSID/radio combination is a separate wireless interface with it's own BSSID.  So if you are broadcasting 2 SSIDs from both radios on a dual-radio AP, it will have 4 separate BSSID's (MAC addresses) in the air.

You will find that they will "cheat" the system a little bit by using the wired MAC address as one of the BSSIDs since in a properly configured wireless network, any traffic from the wireless interface should not make it's way back to the wire.

For example, I am looking at an older Cisco (Airespace-rebranded) dual radio AP with one WLAN/SSID on each radio.  In the air I see 00:0B:85:xx:80 (5GHz) and 00:0B:85:xx:8F (2.4GHz).  The wired MAC is 00:0B:85:xx:80.